# Give an example of a non-zero polynomial belonging to $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$that produces the zero function over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/(p)$. Give an example of a non-zero polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ that produces the zero function $f:\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: $x^{p}-x$ is an example.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown woops, thanks

Comment: Why is $x^{p-1} - 1$ problematic? Since $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ anyway

Comment: Have you tried plugging in each element of $\Bbb F_p$ into that? You might want to try it for, say, $p = 2$.

Comment: Ah! Right, of course